# The Grandfather Paradox

Tags: cipher

You are rummaging though your grandpa's old stuff and see an old [PDP-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-8) with a note attached to it. On one side there is the following key combo:

> 

Here is a picture of the characters (written in the proper context):

[image: Key combo]

On the other side you find the following text:

> EXTRANEOUS DATA INCLUDED. FOR USE WITH WINDOWS NT.

What is Grandpa saying?

Answer (score 8):

These characters

> are all in the Unicode Private Use Area. They have character codes `F0__`: the first is `F054`, the second is `F068`...
>
>  Removing the "F0" at the start of each character code gives hexadecimal ASCII, which reads `The rep is a Lie`.

Comment: You got it, but not in the way I intended it. Maybe I should start checking my puzzles for shortcuts :P

Comment: so do PDP-8 and WINDOWS NT have anything to do with the solution actually or are they there just to mislead and make it harder?

Comment: @morgwai I suspect that they have something to do with the *intended* solution - something about those PUA characters being accessible in Windows NT through some key combination, perhaps? - but I skipped over that completely.